# Keep only the first page of a PDF document with PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I have many PDFs that are generated and uploaded to my server.
The problem is they contain the same page three times (3 pages in total with the same content).
My goal is to edit the PDF with PHP so that it contains only one page.
Is there any library that allows me to simply load a PDF and keep only the first page?

Thank you!

Comment: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ -> https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: https://github.com/bensquire/php-pdftk-toolkit
claims that it can split pdfs. It is only a wrapper for a command-line util but it might be what you are searching for

Comment: use fpdf brother its useful   www.fpdf.org

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Found the solution in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FPDF (http://www.fpdf.org/) or MDPF (http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) are great libraries for work with PDF files. I have experiences only with creating PDF; but I assume that one of those libraries can solve your problem.

Edit: Here is some example with FPDF

https://gist.github.com/maccath/3981205

Comment: Thank you, forgot to accept it faster. The example in the edit was a lifesaver. It's one of those things that you can write yourself but you really don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

Using [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/), you can create a function to extract the first page of a PDF file:

```
function first_page ($path) {
    $pdf = new FPDI();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->setSourceFile($path);
    $pdf->useTemplate($pdf->importPage(1));

    return $pdf;
}
```

Then output the extracted PDF as you would do with [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm):

```
// Extract first page from /path/to/my.pdf
// and output it to browser with filename "MyPDF".
first_page('/path/to/my.pdf')->Output('MyPDF', 'I');
```