# Base64 convert to pdf file: How to make it display the first page of the pdf only? Is it possible?

Tags: php, database, pdf

I'm successfully converting Base64 that I got from Database and display it as pdf. The problem now, I want it to display only the first page of the pdf. It is possible? How to do this? Can I easily set the page number? Or any other ways???

Below is code how I display the Base64 into a pdf view :

```
echo '<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($content).'" type="application/pdf" style="height:100%;width:100%"></object>';
                    exit();
```

Note***$content is the Base64 that I retrieve from database. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This might answer the question, already asked at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279274/keep-only-the-first-page-of-a-pdf-document-with-php